# Incorrect BMP displaying in SquareChase

Tags: c#, bmp

I'm trying the code for the game SquareChase shown in XNA 4.0 Game programming by Example by Jaeger. The program is running through the VS2010 ide but the texture it is displaying is not the texture i drew. I've checked the Content directory and that holds the correct texture so i dont know where the incorrect texture is coming from. Can someone please help with this weird error?

I have got this code to work okay on another computer so i don't know what the problem is.
Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no error. The code was changing the color of a yellow texture to a red tint inline.